# How to classify the manifold $SU(3)/(SU(2)\times U(1))$ as a Riemannian manifold.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I'm extremely new to topology and am trying to self-learn to better understand different applications in physics. I am interested in the coset  $M=SU(3)/(SU(2)\times U(1))$.

I'm not entirely sure what I can say about this space. Is it diffeomorphic to a more-well-known space? I was considering that maybe it could also be written as: $$\frac{SU(3)}{SU(2)\times U(1)}\simeq\frac{S^{5}}{U(1)}?$$

However, I'm not entirely sure that is valid. I'm also guessing it's not simply connected due to the $U(1)$ quotient. I don't believe $SU(2)\times U(1)$ is a normal subgroup of $SU(3)$ so it's not itself a Lie group. Essentially, I'm asking if someone can enlighten me on properties of this manifold. Or how I would go about solving said problems myself. I apologize if the question isn't straight forward. In particular, what are it's properties as a Riemannian manifold?

I DO get that $SU(3)$ acts transitively on M, with $SU(2)\times U(1)$ being the point stabilizer. I would be happy just figuring out whether it's parallellizable or not.

**EDIT**
I believe it's (isomorphic to) the complex projective space $CP^2$ can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I confirm that $S^5/U(1)$ is isomorphic to $CP^2$, which is simply connected by the way.

Comment: @Didier after looking at it again, I'm thinking $CP^2$ is actually the double cover of the space I'm looking at. Due to the $U(n)$ being the **semi**-direct product of $SU(n)$ and $U(1)$ rather than the direct product.